# Force django cache updating

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a site with pages hierarchy, which shows tables based on complex calculation from values stored in database. That database can be updated by external application. During to long time of calculation, I prefer to use per-page caching to show result pages (I'm using DatabaseCache). After external updating of database, I can clear cache, but I want to refresh it (create new one instead) before user's visit (assuming that user will see only next cached version). 
Is any way in Django to force refreshing cache by external application?
Comes to mind only calling some Django code from external app, which will call all the pages urls one-by-one, after cache deleting..
Will be grateful for your advice anyway

Answer (score -1):

in your external script you can do

```
import django
from django.core.cache import cache

django.setup() # Needed to make django ready from the external script
cache.clear() # Flush all the old cache entry.
```

Comment: Now i`m using manage.py-invoking external script to clear cache in this way. This script called by external app, but i need to create  new cache after that...

Comment: What I mean is, in you external script you do

`django.setup()`
`# Here you do whatever you need on the external script`
`cache.clear()`

This way the cache will always be clear after your external script has finished.

You do not have to recreate a new cache, django will automatically populate the cache as soon as it gets a request